# My for loop won't repeat, there is most likely a line of code that I'm missing

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I'm supposed to write any number in an input textfield and then have the sum of the ten numbers after that number be displayed in a dynamic textfield.

My issue is that I can't find a way to properly do this. My code is currently:

```
var tall:Number=0;

btnSum.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Sum);

function Sum(e)
{
    for(var i:Number=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        tall=Number(txtInn.text)+Number(i);
        txtUt.text=String(tall);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate an answer using basic code, as I am currently in a beginner course. I most likely don't know how to properly do this because I am not too familiar with for-loops.

Quick-edit: What my code currently does is simply add the number I write + 10. Instead of looping. I tried to put

```
{
tall=Number(txtInn.text)+Number(i);
txtInn.text=String(tall);
txtUt.text=txtInn.text;
}
txtInn.text="";
```

But that only accomplishes my goal if the number I write is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want an input of (for example) `1`, and the output being `2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11 = 65`

```
 function Sum(e) {
    var sum:int = 0;
    var input = int(txtInn.text);

    for(var i:int=input + 1; i<= input + 10; i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
}
```

Remember to keep your sum outside of the loop so it does not get reevaluated each iteration. The operation of `sum += i` is equivalent to `sum = sum + i`.

Comment: You understand my question correctly, but I don't get how I get the output to be what I want with the code you have written.

Also, sum+=i ..?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out now. But I still don't get the meaning of +=, do you mind telling me?

edit: Is it basically that it pluses with each iteration of i until i=10, and then it finds the sum of it? That's what I get out of it anyway.

Thanks a lot for the answer man!

Comment: @Sebbern The operation of sum += i is equivalent to sum = sum + i.

Answer (score 0):

You can also calculate that sum without using a `for` loop because here you want to get the [sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) of the members of a finite [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), which you can get with a simple formula :

```
Sn = ( n / 2 )( a1 + an )
```

where `n` is the number of elements (10 in your case), `a1` is the first element and `an` is the last one.

Example :

```
s = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10;
```

so using that formula :

```
s = (10 / 2) (1 + 10)
s = 55
```

Hopa that can help.